# sparql queries with round brackets throw exception

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am trying to extract labels from DBpedia for some persons. I am partially successful now, but I got stuck in the following problem. The following code works.

```java
public class DbPediaQueryExtractor {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String entity = "Aharon_Barak";
        String queryString ="PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> SELECT * WHERE {dbres:"+ entity+ "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),\"en\"))}";
        //String queryString="select *     where { ?instance <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>;  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  ?o FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),\"en\"))  } LIMIT 5000000";
        QueryExecution qexec = getResult(queryString);
        try {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
            for ( ; results.hasNext(); )
            {
                QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                System.out.print(soln.get("?o") + "\n");
            }
        }
        finally {
            qexec.close();
        }
    }

    public static QueryExecution getResult(String queryString){
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        //VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, graph);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
        return qexec;
    }
}
```

However, when the entity contains brackets, it does not work. For example,

```
String entity = "William_H._Miller_(writer)";
```

leads to this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 86.`

What is the problem?

Comment: can you give the content of line 86? Also it looks a little bit like a syntax error for me.

Comment: Round brackets (or parentheses, in my local dialect) are used to surround function arguments in SPARQL, e.g., in `concat('[',?x,']')`, so I'd expect that this is a syntax error.  You'll probably need to use the full form of your URI, surrounded by `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took some copying and pasting to see what exactly was going on.  I'd suggest that you put newlines in your query for easier readability.  The query you're using is:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * WHERE
{
  dbres:??? <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o 
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
}
```

where `???` is being replaced by the contents of the string `entity`.  You're doing absolutely no input validation here to ensure that the value of `entity` will be legal to paste in.  Based on your question, it sounds like `entity` contains `William_H._Miller_(writer)`, so you're getting the query:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * WHERE
{
  dbres:William_H._Miller_(writer) <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o 
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
}
```

You can paste that into the [public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), and you'll get a similar parse error message:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 6: syntax error at 'writer' before ')'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * WHERE
{
  dbres:William_H._Miller_(writer) <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?o 
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
}
```

Better than hitting DBpedia's endpoint with bad queries, you can also use [the SPARQL query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), which reports for that query:

> Syntax error: Lexical error at line 4, column 34.  Encountered: ")" (41), after : "writer"

In Jena, you can use the ParameterizedSparqlString to avoid these sorts of issues.  Here's your example, reworked to use a parameterized string:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;

public class PSSExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // Create a parameterized SPARQL string for the particular query, and add the 
        // dbres prefix to it, for later use.
        final ParameterizedSparqlString queryString = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "SELECT * WHERE\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  ?entity rdfs:label ?o\n" +
                "  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),\"en\"))\n" +
                "}\n"
                ) {{
            setNsPrefix( "dbres", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" );
        }};

        // Entity is the same. 
        final String entity = "William_H._Miller_(writer)";

        // Now retrieve the URI for dbres, concatentate it with entity, and use
        // it as the value of ?entity in the query.
        queryString.setIri( "?entity", queryString.getNsPrefixURI( "dbres" )+entity );

        // Show the query.
        System.out.println( queryString.toString() );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/William_H._Miller_(writer)> rdfs:label ?o
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
}
```

You can run this query at the public endpoint and get [the expected results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/William_H._Miller_%28writer%29%3E%20rdfs%3alabel%20?o%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28?o%29,%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on).   Notice that if you use an `entity` that doesn't need special escaping, e.g.,

```java
final String entity = "George_Washington";
```

then the query output will use the prefixed form:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * WHERE
{
  dbres:George_Washington rdfs:label ?o
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?o),"en"))
}
```

This is very convenient, because you don't have to do *any* checking about whether your suffix, i.e., `entity`, has any characters that need to be escaped;  Jena takes care of that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Joshua Taylor for taking the time and helping. I run the generated query and it worked. However, running your code throws another exception:                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/NodeFactory
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString.setIri(ParameterizedSparqlString.java:720)
 at nl.cwi.kba2013.apps.PssExample.main(PssExample.java:26)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString.setIri(ParameterizedSparqlString.java:720)
 ....

Comment: @use1967220 If you get that error that suggests a class path issue (likely multiple versions of ARQ on your class path).  What version(s) of ARQ (and any other Jena libraries) are you using?

Comment: @RobV, Thank you so much. That was indeed the problem

Comment: @Joshua_Taylor the "expected results" hyperlink is generating an error

Comment: @Kristian Interesting;  it was copied and pasted from the DBpedia search results, but something was breaking in between.  I fixed the link (by linking to the results of an equivalent, but slightly modified, query).