# How to retrieve person names with punctuation marks from DBPedia?

Tags: r, uri, sparql, dbpedia

I am currently querying DBPedia for a list of person names by using the SPARQL package in R. When I retrieve a list of names by SPARQL, there appears a problem that some names in the form of URI, which contains **punctuation marks** (such as "," or "(") can't be recognized by SPARQL query, e.g.:

```
   endpoint="http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql"
   query= "SELECT COUNT (*){
   dbpedia-de:Johannes_Aurifaber_(Vimariensis) ?p ?o
   }"
   qd=SPARQL(endpoint,query)
```

It turns out to be an error: *XML content does not seem to be XML: 'Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 3: syntax error at 'Vimariensis' before ')'*.
But if I change the query to this:

```
    endpoint="http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql"
    query= "SELECT COUNT (*){
    <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Johannes_Aurifaber_(Vimariensis)> ?p ?o 
    }"
    qd=SPARQL(endpoint,query)
```

Everything turns out well. But is there any way to modify the first query, as it is more convenient to do query for a list of person names.

Comment: Also have a look at [sparql queries with round brackets throw exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18232010/1281433).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to put  `\` before special characters, and it is a valid SPARQL query. This is a valid SPARQL query:

```
SELECT (count(*) as ?count)
where {
    dbpedia-de:Johannes_Aurifaber_\(Vimariensis\)  ?p ?o 
}
```

[image]
However, each endpoint has some specific restrictions. Thus, (as per Joshua's comment) Virtuoso simply allows lots of things that aren't legal, and doesn't accept everything that is legal.

Comment: "However, each endpoint has some specific restrictions. Thus, Virtuoso doesn't simply like \ in the query."  It's not that endpoints have specific restrictions;  Virtuoso simply allows lots of things that **aren't** legal, and doesn't accept everything that **is** legal.  (But aside from that, good answer. :)).

Comment: Thanks, I rephrased it, as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Artemis@Taylor When I query names with **umlaut** or **hyphen** such as “Georg_III._(Anhalt-Plötzkau)” or "Friedrich_von_Sachsen_(1504–1539)" like this:        'endpoint="http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql"
query= "SELECT COUNT (*){
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Georg_III._(Anhalt-Plötzkau)> ?p ?o 

}" ' there still exists errors. Do you know why?

Comment: But that resource (Georg_III) doesn't exist. I checked by `SELECT distinct ?s{ 
?s ?p ?o 
filter(contains(str(?s), "Anhalt"))
}` and it doesn't show up. So I am assuming either it is present in a regional dbpedia, or your link is wrong. If you click on the resource it must open up, which it doesn't. This suggest you have an incorrect uri.

Comment: @Artemis Sorry ;) it should be like this:    '    ''    endpoint="http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql"
  query= "SELECT COUNT (*){
  <de.dbpedia.org/resource/Georg_III._(Anhalt-Plötzkau)> ?p ?o

}"     '

Comment: So if you write `SELECT COUNT (*){ <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Georg_III._(Anhalt-Plötzkau)> ?p ?o}` it gives you the answer. You are missing the WHOLE uri.