# How to add special categories in sparqlwrapper in python

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I am using the following sparql query using sparqlwrapper as follows.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
my_category = 'dbc:Meteorological_concepts'
sparql.setQuery(f" ASK {{ {my_category}  skos:broader{{1,3}} dbc:Medicine }} ")
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results['boolean'])
```

As mentioned above it works fine with categories that do not have brackets (e.g., `dbc:Meteorological_concepts`). However, when I enter a category with brackets (i.e `my_category = dbc:Elasticity_(physics)`) I get the following error.

```
b"Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 4: syntax error at 'physics' before ')'\n\nSPARQL query:\ndefine sql:big-data-const 0 \n#output-format:application/sparql-results+json\n\n    ASK { dbc:Elasticity_(physics) skos:broader{1,3} dbc:Medicine }\n"
CRITICAL: Exiting due to uncaught exception <class 'SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed'>
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: This is an issue with DBpedia URIs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232010/sparql-queries-with-round-brackets-throw-exception)

Comment: @chrisis thanks a lot. It would be really great if you could post it as an answer :)

Comment: Try to use full URIs: `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Elasticity_(physics)>`.

Comment: @EmJ Sorry for my delayed comment. I am getting `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`. Can you please give a suggestion to make it run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am rewriting what @StanislavKralin mentioned in the above comment. I always try to use full URL in the SPARQL code, particularly when there is special character in SPARQL query.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
my_category = '<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Elasticity_(physics)>'
sparql.setQuery(f" ASK {{ {my_category}  skos:broader{{1,3}} dbc:Medicine }} ")
results = sparql.query().convert()
print(results['boolean'])
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed comment. I am getting `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`. Can you please give a suggestion to make it run?